# ARGOCD: can post-sync-hook be triggered once after multiple apps are deployed in argocd

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, argocd

I have added a post-sync-hook.yaml for an app in argocd and it works perfectly fine once the app is deployed and synced.
but I have multiple apps to be deployed and I dont want the post-sync-hook to run everytime. so is there a way to make it run only once after all the apps are deployed. or any other alternative to trigger a job from argocd once all the apps are deployed and are in sync.

I tried to add post-sync-hook.yaml to appofapps repository, but when I make changes to my app1 or app2 repo it doesnt affect the sync process of appofapps and hence post-sync-hook is not getting triggered.

below is the structure I tried to execute, I want to run post-sync-hook once my app1 and app2 are deployed.

```
app1
--values.yaml
--templates
  --api.yaml

app2
--values.yaml
--templates
  --api.yaml

appofapps
--values.yaml
--templates
  --app1.yaml
  --app2.yaml
  --post-sync-hook.yaml
```

Comment: ArgoCD handles synchronization on an app-by-app basis; there's not really any way to determine, "when all the apps are deployed an in sync". What if just one app has changes? What if one app has changes and then a couple minutes later another app has changes? Do you run your post-sync job once? Or twice? If once, how do you know when it's safe to run?

Comment: @larsks suppose I have 3 apps and app1 is getting deployed, I will have an interval as 10min to check if any other 2 apps have started the deployment 
-- if no, then post-sync-hook needs to be triggered. 
-- If yes, it will wait till all apps are deployed ,again monitor for 10 mins and trigger the post-sync-job

is this feasible in any way?